# Why isn't sign in with apple button working?

Tags: swiftui, firebase-authentication, sign-in-with-apple

When I drag out the SignInWithAppleButton control using swiftui, this is the code that is shown. However, I get the error message "Argument passed to call that takes no arguments". The compiler only allows the project to build when SignInWithAppleButton() is used.

I've found lots of code online that uses the below format. Why isn't it working now? What is the correct alternative if onRequest and onCompletion can't be used?

```
            SignInWithAppleButton(
            onRequest: { request in
                
            },
            onCompletion: { result in
                
            }
        )
```

Comment: For those having a similar issue when running an iOS app on M1 Mac, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68879028

Comment: I had exactly the same issue! Finally realized that elsewhere in my app I had created a separate instance(months ago) of `SignInWithAppleButton()` which was configured without the `onRequest` or `onCompletion` handlers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

works for me on macos 12.beta using xcode 13.beta, target ios 14.5 and macCatalyst 11.3. What system are you using?

```
import SwiftUI
import AuthenticationServices

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SignInWithAppleButton(onRequest: { request in
             print("onRequest")
         },
         onCompletion: { result in
            print("onCompletion")
         }
        ).frame(width: 222, height: 66)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm on Xcode 12.5. Maybe this problem is specific to that version. Good to know that it will likely go away once I upgrade. Although, I don't plan on updating to the beta quite yet.

Comment: so the code above does not work for you at all, is that correct? I would hold off for a while upgrading to macOS 12 and Xcode 13, it is still very beta and buggy and slow. It would be good if someone could check the code above with Xcode 12.5.

Comment: @workingdog I have checked it with Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262), and it works.

Comment: Key was to import AuthenticationServices.