# SwiftUI SignInWithAppleButton onCompletion never get called on M1 Mac

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-sign-in

The alternative title is "SwiftUI Sign in with Apple button does not work on M1 Mac".

Environment macOS v11.4, Xcode Version 12.5.1, MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)

The following `SignInWithAppleButton` code block works fine on iOS simulators and real devices. However, the completion handler never gets triggered when running it on an M1 Mac. Reading the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/signinwithapplebutton) and it seems to be available on macOS 11.0+.

[image]

Is this a known SwiftUI issue because there is no such issue when I am using an UIKit implementation?

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(
    .continue,
    onRequest: { request in
        request.requestedScopes = [.email]
        print(">>> auth on request") // <- Get called on click
    },
    onCompletion: { result in
        print(">>> auth completed") // <- Never get called
        switch result {
        case let .success(auth):
            switch auth.credential {
            case let credential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:
                let identityToken = credential.identityToken
                if let idToken = identityToken {
                    Dummy.signUpOrLogInWithApple(idToken: idToken)
                }
            default:
                print(">>> default case")
            }
        case let .failure(error):
            print(">>> Sign in with Apple failed", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
)
```

[image]

<del>Not a solution for this problem but a workaround is to continue using the UIKit version of “Sign in with Apple”,~~ https://github.com/Q42/iOS-Demo-SignInWithApple-SwiftUI/blob/master/iOS-Demo-SignInWithApple-SwiftUI/SignInWithAppleButton.swift</del>

I think it is most likely a SwiftUI issue. Tried a wrapped UIKit SignInWithAppleButton however the problem persists. I wonder if this is caused by the missing of `presentationAnchor` which makes it unusable on macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IF THIS HAPPENED TO YOU JUST RESTART YOUR MAC!!!** and then it would work just as expected. No need to use a wrapped UIKit `SignInWithAppleButton`. I think it is most likely an iOS on M1 compatibility issue.

[image]

<del>Tried a wrapped UIKit SignInWithAppleButton however the problem persists. I wonder if this is caused by the missing of `presentationAnchor` which makes it unusable on macOS.</del>

<del>Not a solution for this problem but a workaround is to continue using the UIKit version of “Sign in with Apple”,~~ https://github.com/Q42/iOS-Demo-SignInWithApple-SwiftUI/blob/master/iOS-Demo-SignInWithApple-SwiftUI/SignInWithAppleButton.swift</del>